# Python : How making an attribute private stop the program to go into an infinite loop ? (Private v/s Public attribute)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, private

I am a naive to Object oriented concept in python. While reading the OOP concept from [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) I encounter an example.

```
class P1:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x

e = P(x = 2100)
f = e.x*2

print(f)
2000
```

If I don't make my variable private (in case of class P2) then I guess it will run into an infinite loop.

```
class P2:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.x = 1000
        else:
            self.x = x

e = P(x = 2100) #Infinite loop
```

In order to inspect what actually class P2 is doing I restructured my code to

```
class P2:
    def __init__(self,x):
        print('init area1')
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        print('property area2')
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print('setter area3')
        if x < 0:
            print('setter area4')
            self.x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            print('setter area5')
            self.x = 1000
        else:
            print('setter area6')
            self.x = x
```

When I tried to run P2(x = 2100) it gives me an unstoppable output like:

```
init area1
setter area3
setter area5
setter area3
setter area6
setter area3
setter area6
setter area3
setter area6.......
```

It appears that my program first called init method and after that it is continuously running back and forth from **setter area 3** to **setter area 6**.
Can anyone explain

1. what is happening behind the scene ? How the program is running ?
2. Why magic private attribute are making here so that the program is not running into an infinite loop
3. How @property and @x.setter are related to each other here ? Can't I write @setter without writing @property

I know these are basic questions but I went through so much of online stuff and I didn't find a better answer to these question.

Answer (score 2):

> "Why magic private attribute are making here so that the program is
>   not running into an infinite loop"

It is actually not a good place to use double-underscore name-mangling. I like that tutorial, except for that one detail. You can use a single underscore, or any valid python identifier *except* the one occupied by the property, and you will see the same effect.

A `property` is an object that implements [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).  It is a handy descriptor, for a common descriptor use-case. But we can make our own descriptor types.

Fundamentally, a descriptor is any python type that implements any combination of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`.

These will get invoked when you do `some_object.some_attribute`, `some_object.some_attribute = value`, and `del some_object.some_attribute` where `some_attribute` is a descriptor on `some_object.__class__`.

So, consider a concrete example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
...         print('inside Foo.__get__')
...         return 42
...
>>> class Bar:
...     foo = Foo()
...
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.foo
inside Foo.__get__
42
```

Descriptors *intercept* attribute access and modification, and deletion *on the instance of the class that has the descriptor as an attribute* to allow for all sorts of fun stuff.

Notice, The descriptor belongs to the class:

```
>>> vars(bar)
{}
>>> vars(Bar)
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'foo': <__main__.Foo object at 0x1025272e8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Bar' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Bar' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

If I set an instance attribute as the same name as the class attribute holding the property, the normal python behavior of shadowing occurs:

```
>>> bar.foo = 99
>>> bar.foo
99
>>> vars(bar)
{'foo': 99}
```

But we can control this, we can implement `__set__`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
...       return 42
...    def __set__(self, obj, val):
...       print('nah-ah-ah')
...
...
>>> class Bar:
...     foo = Foo()
...
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.foo
42
>>> bar.foo = 99
nah-ah-ah
>>> bar.foo
42
```

The `property` object just lets you provide functions that will get delegated to when you use `property.__get__`, `property.__set__`, and `property.__delete__`. The docstrings is quite informative, just use `help(property)` in a python shell:

```
class property(object)
 |  property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)
 |
 |  Property attribute.
 |
 |    fget
 |      function to be used for getting an attribute value
 |    fset
 |      function to be used for setting an attribute value
 |    fdel
 |      function to be used for del'ing an attribute
 |    doc
 |      docstring
 |
 |  Typical use is to define a managed attribute x:
 |
 |  class C(object):
 |      def getx(self): return self._x
 |      def setx(self, value): self._x = value
 |      def delx(self): del self._x
 |      x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
 |
 |  Decorators make defining new properties or modifying existing ones easy:
 |
 |  class C(object):
 |      @property
 |      def x(self):
 |          "I am the 'x' property."
 |          return self._x
 |      @x.setter
 |      def x(self, value):
 |          self._x = value
 |      @x.deleter
 |      def x(self):
 |          del self._x
```

So whatever you decorate with `@property.setter`, you can imagine that get's passed to `property(fset=<whatever>)`. So now, whenever your instance tries to set `x.some_attribute = value` where `.some_attribute` is a property on `class X:`, the the `property.__set__` is invoked, you can imagine it goes `x.some_attribute = value` gets translated into `X.some_attribute.__set__(x, value)`

So, to get to the **crux of your question**, why the infinite recursion, because using `obj.x = val` where `.x` is a *property*, will call `fset`, but in your *fset you use `obj.x = val`*, and `fset` *gets called again*, and here is your hidden recursion.

The `@decorator` syntax is for convenience, and always accepts the *getter* first, but you can simply provide only the setter using the long-form way:

```
>>> class Weird:
...    def setx(self, value):
...       self._x = value
...    x = property(fset=setx)
...
>>> w = Weird()
>>> w.x = 'foo'
>>> w.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: unreadable attribute
```

I highly recommend reading the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Spoiler alert, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` are all descriptors, and so is how Python magically passes instances to methods (that is, *all function objects are descriptors who's `__get__` method passes the instance as the first argument to the function itself when accessed by an instance on a class!*. It also shows Python implementations of all of these things, including how you could implement `property` in pure Python!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. One more thing I am not able to understand here is that in case of class P1 how self.__x = 1000 able to set the value for self.x despite the case that property is defined for x. Please explain.

Comment: @user110244 it doesn't, it sets the value for `self.__x` which is what the property getter returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have two more questions :
1) Inside class P2 when it is executed it never prints "property area" . Is this mean program is not entering the property area ? I am confused about the program flow now. 
As per my understanding the flow is init > property (go to setter to check property)> setter (return value from there) ? 
2) In class P1 if I change the code in setter to elif > 1000: self.__y = 1000 it still return the value even when there is not self.__y in "@property". Shouldn't it break if it doesn't find self.__y or returning what is not in "@property" ?